# What is the black arrow in top right corner on top of all windows?

Tags: gnome, budgie

I think I've got this weird arrow since I installed Ubuntu 18.04. It is annoying, because I can't click a tab in a browser which is under this arrow. And I am just worried, what that is. It is always there
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is typically the image of a (Budgie-) applet with an empty or incorrectly showing popover. Most likely one of your applets is not loading correctly.

#### To find out

Just look through the list of installed applets (loaded into the panel, as Budgie Settings shows), and/or run from a terminal `budgie-panel --replace&`, and see if anything specifics shows up in the panel, pointing to the misbehaving applet.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is much appreciated; I like budgie but this has been driving me crazy. Running the command fixes the arrow, though it also changes the order of icons. I'm not totally sure how to interpret the output, but the message `Failed to find extension for: ShowTime` suggests to me that it's an issue with the clock, which I believe because the clock app is constantly crashing. Thanks again!

Comment: @svangordon ongoing insight learns that it is most likely DropBy. Which applet is crashing? the desktop clock? That would be strange. That should be rock solid. Also: what is your budgie (Ubuntu) version?If you want, we can discuss this further here: https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/ please ping me if so.